# Is it possible to bake materials to textures?

Tags: materials

I have this funny little goat model, and the colors and everything looks fine (I used assign material)

[image]

But then, if I change to texture mode, (I need it to have a texture, too)
because it has no texture, it looks like this!

[image]

How do I make a material a texture?

Comment: You could bake Full Render to the texture (note that lighting will be taken into account so the mesh should be lit evenly).

Comment: I believe this guy does this with cycles in this video so it may prove useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57xL0vjSC00&list=PLlV0HYg1k1bY3NqvGq9iSysiCHJqDhpes&index=3

Answer (score 1):

Materials contain amongst others a diffuse part. In short, this is the part that gives the model its colors. You can certainly bake specific parts of the assigned material to a texture in both Blender internal and Cycles. Since both methods differ from each other a little it would be good to know which render engine you use.

Answer (score 0):

A material can have a texture, among some other properties. You can add a texture to your object, but it won't be as easy as giving materials with colors to the different parts of your object. A texture normally is an image that wraps around the surface of your object.

It would help to know what you are trying to do, to see if you really need textures and what kind of texturing method you have to use. Otherwise, I suggest you read a bit (or watch tutorials) about "Texturing in Blender".